# Can a power that succeeded and then was made Innate have its target changed later?

Tags: psionics, anima-beyond-fantasy

Let's say a psychic uses, just as an example power, *Organic Telekinesis* (sorry if the name's not literal, I'm translating it from Spanish) on an enemy, succeeds and makes it innate. After a while a stronger enemy shows up.  Three questions arise:

- Can the psychic change the target of his innate *telekinesis* to the new enemy?
- Can the psychic affect both enemies with his innate *telekinesis* (provided he can handle enough Kg)?
- If yes to either of those, what kind of action does the psychic need to take for including that enemy: Active or Passive?

Basically the question is **how do Innate Powers work with changing targets**, and dividing it into those three parts is only to illustrate my points of doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the other answer. I only have access to the english core rule book (is there even an Exxet for psionics?) so I cannot speak to the rules present in any other books. Page numbers refer to the printed page numbers in the english rules, and I will attempt to list headers where appropriate.

### Activating Psychic Powers

In order to execute a psychic powers you roll a d100, and add Psychic Potential. Compare this to the difficulty table on the power.

- Chapter 13, pg.192 *The use of Psychic Powers*

### Innate Slots

Some powers can be maintained, and you need to put them in innate slots.

> Innate slots allow the psychic to be subconsciously tie one of their Powers to their will so that they can be used effortlessly every turn (...) It is necessary for characters to use a Power once before they can keep it active.

Once the power is activated, you drop it into an innate slot, and

> they will not need to roll any dice to use it

This power operates in the natural difficulty range of the characters Psychic Potential or the minimum activation level (because you have no roll to add to it)

- Chapter 13, pg.194 *Acquiring an Innate Slot*

### Psychic Projection

You need to use Projection to hit enemies at range (Except for telepathic abilities, which expressly do not require a Projection roll)

- Chapter 13, pg.195 *Psychic Projection*

So we now have all the parts needed to know how to use our psychic abilities, and place them into innate slots! Here's a (simplified!) breakdown:

1. Activate a power
2. Roll Psychic Potential to see how well it works
3. Choose whether to drop the ability into an innate slot
4. (If applicable) Roll Projection to determine range
5. Resolve the ability

This means that once you have activated a power successfully and dropped it into an innate slot, you are free to keep using that power as much as you like, with new Projection rolls whenever you want to use the ability on a new target, to whether the target is within range.

Let's apply this to Organic Psychokinesis:

1. Activate Organic Psychokinesis
2. Roll Potential to get a difficulty level
3. Choose to drop into innate slot (dropping to minimum difficulty level, let's assume 120)
4. Roll Projection to determine range (lets assume it worked! Your target is in range!)
5. Target rolls PhR (assume they fail)
6. Check weight limits (assume they're light)
7. You can move the target at Flight Value 4!
8. A new target appears
9. Decide to target them with your innate power
10. Roll Projection to determine range (assume they're in range)
11. Target2 rolls PhR (assume they fail)
12. Check weight limits (including target1, assume they're both light enough)
13. You can move both targets with Flight Value 4!

Now, one aspect of this particular power is that we do not get a rate at which the PhR checks are made. This is up to interpretation by the GM, but I would rule that the targets get a new check each turn to resist being moved by the Psychic.

With ***all*** of that out of the way, I'll directly address your bullet points:

1. Can the psychic change the target of his innate telekinesis to the new enemy?

   Yes, as long as the psychic passes his Projection roll, he is able to target the new enemy with innate powers.
2. Can the psychic affect both enemies with his innate telekinesis (provided he can handle enough Kg)?

   Yes, Organic Psychokinesis (pg. 200) does not give a limit of how many targets can be selected, and even specifies "material objects" in the description. In english this is technically vague wording (especially since the singular "target" is used later) but could easily be interpreted as allowing multiple targets to be affected at one time. Consult your GM.
3. If yes to either of those, what kind of action does the psychic need to take for including that enemy: Active or Passive?

   According to the innate slot rules, this is a passive action, but requires a Projection role on the part of the psychic.

Comment: I've been thinking on this answer for a while, and I don't see any inherent problems with it. I briefly panicked about the implications it would bring to the Ballistics power (free extra attacks), but you can't maintain Ballistics, so it was a non-issue. If anyone sees anything please do let me know, as I'll be applying some of the things I found here to my own sessions.

Comment: The Arcana Exxet contains additional psionic powersets, for future reference, but I don't think it changed the *rules* any.

Answer (score 0):

When a psychic uses one of his powers, he can tie it to a innate ‘slot’, the power stays as it has been used, with the sole exception that the Potential of the power is your Psychic Potential (or the minimum required to be able to use the power).

This means that when you Innate a power, it will stay in the same target.

On your example, you cannot ‘move’ your telekinesis to another target, if you want to affect a new target, you must use Telekinesis again, and either maintain it in a different Innate ‘slot’ or stop maintaining the old one. If you want to affect two different persons, you can divide your Potential to use two powers on the same turn, but both need to be in different Innate ‘slots’.

The Telekinesis power state that is one individual affected per use of power. Again, to affect both on the same turn you must divide your Potential. Besides it will be really strange to calculate Physical Resistances to escape the power…

If you are a Spanish speaker, I suggest you talk to the Spanish community in the [official site](http://www.edgeent.com/foro/anima_beyond_fantasy). They are very knowledgeable and have access to Anima Studio (the creator of the game) official answers.

Comment: I'd appreciate a citation or some kind of source.

Comment: In two days I'll have to award the Bounty. I'd love giving it to you, but I won't for an answer that has no source from the manuals nor any official source. Please, complete your answer.